# Match exactly 10 digits with unknown boundaries?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

Is there any regex I can use to match blocks of exactly 10 digits? For instance, I have this:

```
/\d{10}(?!\d+)/g
```

And this matches `2154358383` when given `2154358383` fine, but is also matches `1213141516` when given `12345678910111213141516`, which I don't want.

What I think I need is a look-behind assertion (in addition to my lookahead already in there), that checks to make sure the character preceding the match is not an integer, but I can't figure out how to do that.

I tried

```
/(?:[^\d]+)\d{10}(?!\d+)/g
```

But that broke my first match of `2154358383`, which is bad.

How can I write this to only match groups of 10 integers (no more, no less) with unknown boundaries?

I should also note that I'm trying to extract these out of a much larger string, so `^` and `$` are out of the question.

Comment: What do you mean by unknown boundaries?  Should "abc1234567890def" match?

Comment: Does it matter what it matches, or just that it matches in the first place?

Comment: "unknown boundaries" in the sense that it's not wrapped in something predictable, like quotes or something... so that I could just match inside the quotes, or from the beginning and ending of the line, etc. Yes, your example `abc1234567890def` should match, but `abc123456789012334567890def` should not.

Comment: Amending my previous comment: the first given example should match as `1234567890`, not as-is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you do something like:

```
([^\d]|^)(\d{10})([^\d]|$)
```

In other words, the beginning of the string or a non-digit, ten digits, then the end of the string or a non-digit. That should solve the cases you looked for above.

You can use the regex like this:

```
var regex = /([^\d]|^)(\d{10})([^\d]|$)/;
var match = regex.exec(s);
var digits = match[2];
```

Comment: This matches the lead and trailing character before and after the match, so `abc1234567890def` returns as `c1234567890d`. I tried this `(?:[^\d]|^)(\d{10})(?:[^\d]|$)`, but I had the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

This should work: `([^\d]|^)\d{10}([^\d]|$)`

Comment: Exactly the same. Pretty funny.

Comment: Oops. Almost the same. Mine was missing a backslash in the last character group. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This should match numbers at the beginning of the string (the `^`) or in the middle/end (the `[^\d]` and the `(?!\d)`.  If you care about the exact match and not just that it matches in the first place, you'll need to grab the first group in the match.

```
/(?:[^\d]|^)(\d{10})(?!\d)/g
```

This would be easier if JavaScript regular expressions supported lookbehind.

Comment: This still matches the leading character (not part of the match), so `abc1234567890def` comes back as `c1234567890`. I wouldn't think so, since you're wrapping it in `(?:)`, though... thoughts?

Comment: @neezer as I said, you need to grab the first group in the match rather than just using the match verbatim.  See [How do you access the matched groups in a javascript regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regex) for details on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

What about the next?

```
perl -nle 'print if /(\b|\D)(\d{10})(\D|\b)/' <<EOF
123456789
x123456789
123456789x
1234567890
x1234567890
1234567890x
12345678901
x12345678901
x12345678901x
EOF
```

will print only

```
1234567890
x1234567890
1234567890x
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var re = /(?:^|[^\d])(\d{10})(?:$|[^\d])/g

re.exec ( "2154358383")
//["2154358383", "2154358383"]
re.exec ( "12345678910111213141516" )
//null
re.exec ( "abc1234567890def" )
//["c1234567890d", "1234567890"]

val = '1234567890 sdkjsdkjfsl 2234567890 323456789000 4234567890';
re.exec ( val )
//["1234567890 ", "1234567890"]
re.exec ( val )
//[" 2234567890 ", "2234567890"]
re.exec ( val )
//[" 4234567890", "4234567890"]
re.exec ( val )
//null
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you said "no ^" but maybe it's okay if you use it like this?:

```
rx = /(?:^|\D)(\d{10})(?!\d)/g
```

Here's a quick test:

```
> val = '1234567890 sdkjsdkjfsl 2234567890 323456789000 4234567890'
'1234567890 sdkjsdkjfsl 2234567890 323456789000 4234567890'
> rx.exec(val)[1]
'1234567890'
> rx.exec(val)[1]
'2234567890'
> rx.exec(val)[1]
'4234567890'
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple with lookbehind:

```
/(?<!\d)\d{10}(?!\d)/g
```

Comment: JS doesn't seem to support lookbehinds `(?<!\d)`; doing that exits my tests with `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<!\d)\d{10}(?!\d)/: Invalid group`

Answer (score -3):

i would cheat and do something like

```
if (myvar.toString().substring(1, 10) = "1234567890") ....
```

:)

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Sorry.

Comment: @Kobi maybe he's going for the [Peer Pressure badge](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/38/peer-pressure)

Comment: oh poop - come on, i even added a smilie face!  I was saying I would cheat by converting it to a string and then comparing the first 10 digits to whatever i was comparing it to.  If it wasn't always the first 10 digits, I could do a IndexOf() on it.  
Dang - didn't expect to get downvoted :(

Comment: I think you've missed the point.  Completely.  It's 10 arbitrary digits.  Not 10 digits he knows in advance.